# Django API is throwing error r("Expecting value", s, err.value)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created the API for restful services. but it is throwing error raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

API url is path('api/(?P\d+)/$', views.EmployeeDetailsCBV.as_view()),

view is class EmployeeDetailsCBV(View):
    def get(self,request,id,*args,**kwargs):
        emp = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        emp_data = {
        'eno':emp.eno,
        'ename':emp.ename,
        'esal':emp.esal,
        'eaddr':emp.eaddr,
        }
        json_data = json.dumps(emp_data)
        return HttpResponse(json_data,content_type='application/json')

Comment: try printing emp.eno and emp.ename maybe missing value.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS if I trying to pass value manually then its working fine but when i am trying to get empo id from user then it is throwing error.

Comment: does the Employee you are fetching has all the values. check in db once for the id you are fetching

Comment: yes that emp id is have value. I think there is issue in url path what I am defining. path('api/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.EmployeeDetailsCBV.as_view()), Can you please conform /(?P<id>\d+)/$' is correct @PavanKumarTS

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using django 2.* you need to use following pattern

```
path('api/<int:id>/', views.EmployeeDetailsCBV.as_view(),name='api')
```

else if you like to use re_path you can use same way as you are using

```
re_path('api/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.EmployeeDetailsCBV.as_view()),
```